# On iPhone X app crashes for the reason 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIStatusBar_Modern

Tags: ios, crash, iphone-x, nsunknownkeyexception, ios11.1.1

My app has a storyboard and it built in Objective C. This app works fine on all other devices but only for iPhone x it crashes for the reason:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIStatusBar_Modern 0x7fcc73e0d680> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key foregroundview.'

I tried all the solutions I found but yet no result.

Comment: Do you get the statusbar in your code or it's used by an external framework? If you use it, can you share with us your code?

Comment: Thanks, @Kerberos, Actually I solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

This exception is often appears when you connect your view to some property and then, rename (for example from `foregroundview` to `foregroundView`) that property or remove it. Try using search by `foregroundview` in your project. And check if there's any result in your storyboard. And when find one - break the connection and create new one to the correct outlet if it's needed